# NullPointerException in PrintWriter object Java chat project

Tags: java, user-interface, nullpointerexception, chat, drag

this is a chat server
I used socket programming to create this chat server
I made output stream using `PrintWriter` object
I had `NullPointerException` in my project but I have no idea why!
the line that have exception is:

```
output.println(jTextField1.getText());
```

I tried all what I know but I couldn't solve this
can any one give me a solution for that please?

```
package chats;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author princessaustralia
 */
public class ChatS extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable
 {
        private Socket link = null;
    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private static int PORT = 4444;

    /**
     * Creates new form ChatS
     */
    public ChatS()
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            Scanner input;
            String message;
            server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            link = server.accept();
            input = new Scanner(link.getInputStream());
            while (true)
            {
            message = input.nextLine();
            jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + "Client Says: " + message + "\n");
            jTextField1.setText("");
        }

    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents()
{

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jButton1.setText("Send");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
        {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
        .addComponent(jTextField1)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(159, 159, 159)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 204, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(0, 12, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                         
{                                             
    try
    {
        PrintWriter output;
        output = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(), true);
        jTextArea1.append("You Sayed: " + jTextField1.getText());
        output.println(jTextField1.getText());
        output.flush();
        jTextField1.setText("");
    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[])
{
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try
    {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels())
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName()))
            {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            new ChatS().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   


}
```

Comment: which line throws the exception?

Comment: Are you using debug option in Eclipse? I am guessing that you are writing this in eclispe.

Comment: @poodle It looks more like written/generated in NetBeans

Comment: this line:        output.println(jTextField1.getText());

Comment: format your code .remove unnecessary netbean generated codes

Answer (score 0):

you are getting NPE because your link is null

Comment: I wrote this:    Socket link; ... only but the exception still appears :(

Comment: she is initializing it in run method. So it cant be because of null link. link = server.accept();

Comment: I just did a    System.out.println("link is " +link); just before  output = new PrintWriter(link.getOutputStream(), true); in her code and it says link is null.link is null
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at example.ChatS.jButton1ActionPerformed(ChatS.java:113)
 at example.ChatS.access$0(ChatS.java:107)
 at example.ChatS$1.actionPerformed(ChatS.java:78)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the clients socket with the server socket. Server is just waiting to accept connections. You did this, ok, but in a Swing application???

There should write something like

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
//get the io streams and talk to the server
```

Maybe this works:

```
PrintWriter output;
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

But the application would talk to itself then.

Ok, here you are:

```
private Socket link = null;
private ServerSocket server = null;
private static int PORT = 4444;

/**
 * Creates new form ChatS
 */
public ChatS() {
this.initComponents();
new Thread(this).start();
}

@Override
public void run() {
try {
    Scanner input;
    String message;
    this.server = new ServerSocket(PORT);

    while (true) {
    this.link = this.server.accept();
    input = new Scanner(this.link.getInputStream());
    message = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(message);
    this.jTextArea1.setText(this.jTextArea1.getText() + "Client Says: " + message + "\n");
    this.jTextField1.setText("");
    }

} catch (final IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

this.jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
this.jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
this.jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
this.jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

this.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

this.jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
this.jTextArea1.setRows(5);
this.jScrollPane1.setViewportView(this.jTextArea1);

this.jButton1.setText("Send");
this.jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(final java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    ChatS.this.jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

final javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this.getContentPane());
this.getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout
    .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(this.jScrollPane1)
    .addComponent(this.jTextField1)
    .addGroup(
        layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(159, 159, 159).addComponent(this.jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
    layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addComponent(this.jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 204,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
        .addComponent(this.jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 28,
            javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addGap(18, 18, 18).addComponent(this.jButton1)
        .addGap(0, 12, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

this.pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(final java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
try {
    PrintWriter output;
    final Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
    output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    this.jTextArea1.append("You Sayed: " + this.jTextField1.getText());
    output.println(this.jTextField1.getText());
    output.flush();
    this.jTextField1.setText("");
} catch (final IOException ex) {
    // Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,
    // ex);
}
}

/**
 * @param args
 *            the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(final String args[]) {
/* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed"
// desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
/*
 * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
 * default look and feel. For details see http://download.oracle.
 * com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
 */
try {
    for (final javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
    }
    }
} catch (final ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (final InstantiationException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (final IllegalAccessException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (final javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ChatS.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
// </editor-fold>

/* Create and display the form */
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    new ChatS().setVisible(true);
    }
});
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
```

First you have to start your thread by new Thread(this).start();. See the constructor.

Next you should create a server socket with each socket request. See method run

And finally you have to create a socket on client side as described above.

Works...

Comment: I really thank you for this ... but this new exception occured :D  ... java.net.SocketException: Socket is not connected

Comment: Ah, ok. I think this is due to the fact, that you only have one connection on the server side (referenced by "link"). There's lots of work left to do like creating a class extending Thread to push the socket connection to. Then a Collection like HashMap to hold all the Threads asf.. Anyway I can't reproduce the Exception here. So it should be a good start.